# "The RPC server is unavailable" only when running script

Tags: windows, powershell

I am having issue with Powershell.I try and run my script which is

```
Param (
[string]$ComputerName
)
$ComputerName = $ComputerName -replace " ", ","
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime' ;EXPRESSION=  {$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}
```

I run it with:

`.\GetBootTime.ps1 -ComputerName localhost,<another computer>`

I get Error Message:

> Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x800706BA).

However if I run:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName localhost,<another computer> | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime' ;EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}
```

which is the main line in the script
then it works.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Most likely the error is telling you it can't communicate with WMI on `<another computer>`.  You could simplify your test to just `.\GetBootTime.ps1 -ComputerName <another computer>`.  The "However if I run:" section of your question isn't very clear - what value does $ComputerName have in that context?

Comment: @FrankBoyne If I run .\GetBootTime.ps1 -ComputerName <another computer> it works fine it just seems to be that when I do two computers than it does not work. Also hopefully made it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you define `Computername` as a string `[string]` rather than a string array `[string[]]`. So the input `localhost,example` isn't interpreted as two computers but one computer named "localhost,example". If you use `[string[]]` (or don't define it) then the `,` character is parsed as the delimiter in an array of string. Since `Get-WmiObject` can take an array, then it would run once for each element of the array.

You could do your own parsing for spaces and commas with `-split`, but its better to use provide a properly formatted array in the first place. `-split` is used because `$ComputerName -replace " ", ","` will just make a `[string]` with commas instead of spaces rather than splitting into multiple elements in an array.

```
Param (
    [string[]]$ComputerName
 )
 # Manual parsing to split space delimited into two elements 
 # e.g. 'localhost Example' into @(localhost,Example) - Not a good practice
 $ComputerName = $ComputerName -split " "
 Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $ComputerName | select csname, @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime' ;EXPRESSION=  {$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}
```